# Jenkins pipeline rtUpload error Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am testing if i can upload files to my artifactory i keep getting this error

```
Bitbucket] Build result notified
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non- 
standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 2]
```

My pipeline looks like this, my Node is running on windows

```
pipeline {
agent {
node {
  label 'MYNODE'
     }
  }

stages {
    stage ('Clone') {
        steps {
            git branch: 'master', url: "https://bitbucket.myorg.com/scm/dwhdat/testdeploy.git"
            }
    }

    stage ('Upload') {
        steps {
             withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', passwordVariable: 'USER_PASS', usernameVariable: 'USER_NAME')]) {
            rtUpload (
                 serverId: 'dwh-art',
                specPath: 'src\\etl\\mysasprogram.sas'
            )
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

the Clone steps runs ok, but somehow it wont par my specPath, can anyone see whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve this my self,
we need to specify some Json in the rtUpload  then it works.

```
  stage ('Upload') {
        steps {

            usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER')])   {*/
            rtUpload serverId: "${ARTIFACTORY_SERVER}", 
            spec: """{
                 
                "files":[ {
                            
                        "pattern": "${ZIP_FILE_NAME}",
                        "target": "${ARTIFACTORY_REPO}"
                         }
                    ]
            }"""
            /* } */

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason i get this error (//) it was a comment mark

```
{
    //"type":"test"
    "date":"01-01-1988",
    "color":"Black"
}
```

It should have been like this when using Postman request

```
{
    "type":"test",
    "date":"01-01-1988",
    "color":"Black"
}
```